# DNN 7 Verification Code and Email - How To Resend, Verify Programmatically When Code Is Available?

Tags: email-verification, dotnetnuke-7

When a user completes registration and logs in for the first time, they are forwarded to some page and are told to go to their email and click the verification link.

We're using DNN 7 and Up.

Sometimes, users don't get the verification email, and as administrators, we'll have to manually verify them via the admin/host UI.

What DNN functions are there to resend the verification email to the user logged in? (I don't want to rebuild the entire verification email body from scratch getting into tabs, skins, and other DNN entities.)

What page/module do I go to to add a button to resend the email verification (and add the verification code textbox and submit button for it)?

Suppose they want to enter the verification code in a text box on the same page (their preference instead of clicking the verification link in their email) - what function[s] do I need to call to do this? (What happened to this verification code textbox that showed up on the login control/module when the user tries to log in for the first time?)